# Android, open an external app inside my app

Tags: android, pdf, layout

i open a PDF with the default reader on the system. 
Someone know if is possible inherits this reader (ex. Thinkoffice or Adobe Reader) into a layout on my app?
Because i need to open a PDF and show an header, or something like that, with a special description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Someone know if is possible inherits this reader (ex. Thinkoffice or Adobe Reader) into a layout on my app?

That is impossible. You cannot embed other applications' UIs into your app.

> Because i need to open a PDF and show an header, or something like that, with a special description..

Put that information into the PDF file itself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think it's possible. You can however fire intents which can be captured by an appropriate application on the phone. This is handled by the OS. I don't know if there is any intent for opening PDFs. Here is a useful library for intents though: http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable. See if you can find something there.